# Call Overloaded Function in Java?

Tags: java, generics, implicit, explicit

How can I call the array function in Java?

Currently it looks like:

```
public static void WriteLine(Object Array[]) {
    for (int I = 0; I < Array.length; ++I) {
        Out.println(Array[I]);
    }
}

public static void WriteLine(Object Text) {
    Out.println(Text);
}
```

I also tried:

```
public static <T> void WriteLine(T Array[]) {
    for (int I = 0; I < Array.length; ++I) {
        Out.println(Array[I]);
    }
}
```

and in my main, I do:

```
int[] I = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
WriteLine(I);
```

I also tried:

```
WriteLine<int[]>(I);
```

Doesn't work..

It prints:
[I@2f56f920

aka the address of the int Array. How can I call the specific array function explicitly or how can I make the compiler know which one to call automatically (implicitly)?

I'm not used to Java/Generics/Object yet.. Just moved from C++ and used to templates :(

Comment: No I want it to print any kind of array.

Comment: Horrible style.  What's up with I as index for loop?  Did you write FORTRAN until recently?  Learn the Sun Java coding style standards.

Comment: After you figure out the solution to this, start following Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with my coding style :S And yes I write Fortran, C++, Haskel, C, PHP, JS, Pascal, Delphi, x86-ASM etc..

In netbeans I pressed right click and then format and thats the style it gave me :S

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Unlike many languages, Java as a [documented set of conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Code conventions are a (non complete?) super-set of code formatting in this case. People are usually less concerned with Java formatting differences as long as it's indented consistently in some fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `int` is not an `Object` so an `int[]` is not an `Object[]`:

```
Integer[] I = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
WriteLine(I);
```

Or you should have `WriteLine` overloaded for all the primitive types:

```
public static void WriteLine(int Array[]) {
...
public static void WriteLine(long Array[]) {
...
```

Comment: Ahh.. Boxed types. I will go for the overload all primitive types instead. Thank you for taking the time to reply. I will accept this as the answer. I thought there was a way to explicitly call a specific overload.

Comment: That is why there are 9 `java.util.Arrays.toString` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would name your array something other than "Array," as Java is confusing the Array class with the Object or T generic class. You may want to also consider using StringBuilder, if all you want is to print each element of your array.

```
public static void write(Object arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Should be good enough.

If you really want to use StringBuilder, and then print, do this:

```
public static void write(Object arr[]) {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: I would name it something else too, but that's not the issue. `Array` probably isn't imported even, but that wouldn't confused the compiler anyway. For example: http://ideone.com/sFgpo7

Answer (score 1):

array of primitive are subtype of java.lang.Object. Overloading is resolved at compile time and the most specific method is selected which in case is writeLine(Object text).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to make sure that the right function is called:

1-

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

2-

```
Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

On a side note, you should follow [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). for example method name should be `writeLine` and the index variable in the loop should be `small case`

Comment: Hmm.. Why is small case? I will do it but I don't know why small case is so important for java? I'm reading the conventions manual someone above linked me to atm. It seems to have ton of small case like you suggest. Just for style?

Comment: Following the language naming convention makes your code more readable to other programmers, otherwise it might look strange and annoying. Each language has a different naming convention for example `WriteLine` is OK for languages like `C#` but it should be `writeLine` in Java.